# Was Mozart black?

Tags: race, musicians

Currently on Facebook and Tumblr I’ve stumbled onto this claim that Mozart was in fact black, and of African descent.

[image: 'The truth', showing a picture of Mozart with black skin color; 'The false (fake)', showing the same picture of Mozart with white skin color; and 'The real Mozart', showing a different black-and-white picture]

[image: Screenshot of Facebook post with picture of Mozart with black skin color, and text starting with 'Mozart was a Moor!']

Is this true?

Comment: This claim is a first for me.

Comment: @Ruut was for me till today, its on reddit, facebook, and tumblr.

Comment: @DJClayworth http://imgur.com/a/3zPmS http://transistor-sister-radio.tumblr.com/post/132872868929/thefingerfuckingfemalefury-afrodeiiity http://i.imgur.com/CYBLCn3.png

Comment: @DJClayworth its just a claim thats gone viral, i didnt say it was a good claim, but i assure you its fairly easy to refute this claim.

Comment: also this http://www.advertolog.com/klara/print-outdoor/mozart-6555755/ klara radio seems to be the start of this picture

Comment: As for the picture on the left, that was actually an [ad campaing](http://www.adeevee.com/2004/03/klara-classical-radio-station-beethoven-mozart-print/). The slogan _'New. Jazz on your classical radio.'_ gives it away, anyway. Also, 'the real Mozart' in the middle is Chevalier de St. George.

Comment: @Swordslayer sounds like an answer to me

Comment: @Himarm well, since I know next to nothing about Mozart himself and only did a reverse image search, all I can say for sure is that those pictures don't prove the original claim.

Comment: @DJClayworth im pretty sure the confusion is because the middle picture is Chevalier de St.George, who is referred to as "the black mozart" and was a contemporary of the real mozart. though i typically dislike self answering

Comment: @Swordslayer. I think that would make a pretty good answer, especially if coupled with pictures of Mozart's father, mother and siblings, none of whom were black.

Comment: Is this a new "thing"?  *Put a false claim on Facebook or Twitter, and see how many people you can fool.*  In my day, we only did these on April 1.

Comment: Moor were arabic, not black, as far as I know.

Comment: @MakorDal the term Moor was used across Europe for anyone from Africa for a very long time. In Dutch there's an old children's song starting "Moorikaantje, zwart als roet", translating as "Moorish boy, black as soot" (and no, no discrimination intended).

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The images backing the original claim are easily disproven. One of them is a taken from the Klara Classical Radio Station 2004 [ad campaign](http://www.adeevee.com/2004/03/klara-classical-radio-station-beethoven-mozart-print/). The campaign modified a portrait by Barbara Kraft, painted 28 years after the death of Mozart:

[image: Portrait of Mozart from 1819]

Kraft based this painting on contemporary paintings of Mozart provided by Mozart's sister, including these (note that the painting on the left really is a different painting from Mozart's lifetime):

[image: Family portrait of Mozart] [image: Portrait of Mozart]

The other is William Ward's portrait of [Monsieur de St. George](http://www.metmuseum.org/collection/the-collection-online/search/365958). His name is still somewhat readable in the small version but is more clear in larger images:

[image: Monsieur de St. George]

[Chevalier de Saint-Georges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalier_de_Saint-Georges) was a contemporary of Mozart's, also known as the "Black Mozart" – which would be a peculiar nickname if they were both black.

Comment: You might also like to add [other pictures of Mozart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart), [his father and mother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopold_Mozart), clearly showing that none of them were black.

Comment: Since the post says the portrait was 'found by a Belgian radio station' (Klara is Belgian) I would assume the writers knew the actual truth when they wrote this.

Comment: And one impressive gentleman he was, if you believe the Wikipedia article. An incredible swordsman, impressive violinist, and excellent composer. So the "Black Mozart" is not just based on some superficial similarity of their wigs, but he was indeed an excellent musician.

Comment: Just for thoroughness, you may want to add something about Mozart's ancestry to address the claim on the OP that he "was a Moor."

Comment: Maybe the nickname was "the black black Mozart," but it got auto-corrected.

Comment: @DJClayworth the same people claiming all images showing Mozart as white are fake would claim those of his parents are fake as well.